# SurfaceView or GLSurfaceview?

Tags: android, canvas, sprite, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

Hello there please help me to decide whether to use SurfaceView or GLSurfaceView.

I will be developing a game for my thesis and I already know how play with Canvas but I'm not sure if  this can handle at least 70 sprites without lag or whatsoever problem. and BTW i will only developing 2d game so please help mo to decide !! Should i study the OpenGL and use GLSurfaceView or it's okay to use Canvas for my simple 2d game thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In android canvas can be actually hardware-accelerated trough OpenGL (because of skia).

With 70 sprites there's no big difference between Canvas and GL. OpenGL requires more configuration, but gives you more ways to optimize drawing.